# How to get text clicked from another program into your own textbox?

Tags: c#, .net

What I mean is how can I get text from another running active window. For example I have a program let's say word or msn. I am chatting with someone while my own program is running in the tray. I want to set a key let's say right click and ctrl to open up my program and get the word I clicked on. 
I am using C#.

Comment: Do you have a single specific application in mind or do you want this to work for all applications?

Comment: Well, I want this to happen with all sorts of applications.

Answer (score 1):

I direct you to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/unified-way-to-scrape-html-from-any-type-of-browser-process/484312#484312) to the question [Unified way to scrape HTML from any type of browser process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/unified-way-to-scrape-html-from-any-type-of-browser-process)

The answer links to an article on [Coding the Wheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com/) which details how to access text in other windows via system dll hooks.  That should have what you require.

Answer (score 1):

you could copy the word and then get the word out of the clip board in your application... otherwise your talking API's for any application you might was to get a word from.